# How do i modify this valid regex for use in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using https://regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/ to create a regex that will be used to filter a list of files in a directory in a c# console application.

The format Im am trying to match is `TLDxxyy` where:
  - `TLD` is a constant
  - `xx` represents 2 digits (00-99)
  - `yy` represents alphanumeric values (00, a9, 0z, zz)
  - case insensitive

Using the 2 sites above, I came up with `tld(\d[0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}).txt` which works wonderfully on my test samples.

```
tld001a8.txt   bad
tls0za8.txt    bad
tls0gy8.txt    bad
tld01a9.txt    good
tld030z.txt    good
tld07zz.txt    good
tld1200.txt    good
```

The following code results in the following error

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path '\w1\whist6\tld('.'

notice the `('.` in my path.

```cs
public static void Test()
{
    var filesToProcess = new List<string>();

    var pathsToSearch = new[] {
        @"\\w1\whist6",
        @"\\w2\whist2"
    };

    var regex = new Regex(@"tld(\d[0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}).txt");


    var hist6Files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(pathsToSearch[0], regex.ToString());
    filesToProcess.AddRange(hist6Files);
}
```

Comment: `GetFileSystemEntries` doesn't understand Regex.  It only understands the very basic wildcard expression `*` you might use on the command-line ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfilesystementries?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFileSystemEntries_System_String_System_String_)):  "The search string to match against the names of file and directories in path. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters, but it doesn't support regular expressions."

Comment: Very minor nitpick, but `\d` and `[0-9]` are essentially the same. Your first capture group can simply be `(\d{2})`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think creating a `Regex` object and then passing only the pattern from it (using `Regex.ToString()`) would gain over just using `@"tld(\d[0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}).txt"` as the second parameter to `GetFileSystemEntries`, because the regex object you created isn't being used at all. It's a waste of code, because you need to use the `regex` object to match the pattern. Your code is the equivalent of *I need to move this pile of stone. Let me grab a wheelbarrow.* and then parking the wheelbarrow next to the pile and carting the stone away in a pail.

Comment: In addition, as @Amy mentions, `GetFileSystemEntries` doesn't use regular expressions anyway. You can do the basic parsing using `tld*.txt`, which will get you a list of all of the files that start with `tld` and have a `.txt` extension, and then use the regex object to test each of those filenames for a specific match.

Comment: Thanks amy and ken. Im going to give @ken suggesting a try.

Comment: @Ken i came up with `Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(pathsToSearch[0], "tld*.txt").Where(path => regex.IsMatch(path)).ToList();` which works. I saw the `pattern` parameter and thought it meant regex pattern. Thank you.

Comment: Nice! That should work.

Comment: @lizzy91 It wouldn't be a bad idea to either self-answer your question with what you found, or accept Andie's answer since their answer is very similar to your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Linq you could do:

```
string[] array = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(pathName)
    .Where(f => searchPattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(f)))
    .ToArray();
```